# Phaser - box2d - Can we maintain the speed even velocity is changing?

Tags: box2d, phaser-framework

I am moving the player using the velocity

Eg: this.player.body.velocity.x =(dynamic value),

when the velocity is more it will move to long distance and the same time speed will be more, when velocity is less it will move to the less distance, here can we maintain the same speed either its moving to short distance or long distance?

Note: I have enabled the box2d for the player

this.game.physics.box2d.enable(this.player);

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you rephrase it differently?

Comment: How we can maintain the same velocity/speed of a moving object even after collision with another object?

Comment: Then you can set `body.restitution = 1` when initializing bodies (on all bodies participating in the collision) to keep the same speed after collision.

Comment: Thank you will try this.